# If statement: Compare analogRead to int

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to complete my heart rate detection code which is supposed to determine a peak for every cycle and use that to calculate the heart rate.

```
 void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int i = 0;
  int peak = 0;
  unsigned long startTime = 0;
  unsigned long endTime = 0;

  startTime = millis();

//This section of the code compares the incoming sensor values to an initial value and replaces that initial value with a higher sensor value and does this for 2 seconds

while(millis() - startTime<=2000){
    if(peak <= analogRead(A0)){
      peak = analogRead(A0);
    }
  }
  endTime = millis();
  Serial.println(peak);//this is the highest value it found after 2 seconds

//This section of the code is supposed to take the peak value from above and compare it with more sensor values for 3 seconds and increment the counter every time the peak value and the sensor value are equal.

while(millis() - endTime <= 3000){
    if(analogRead(A0)== peak){
      i++;
     }
    }
    Serial.println(i);
}
```

The issue that I have is that I get very inconsistent numbers for i, which 
    go as high as 500 and as low as 10. I'm not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Where are you having an issue? With the calculation of `peak` or `i`?

Comment: With the calculation of i.

Comment: Oh, yes. It says that right in the question....Just guessing, but the issue might be the randomness in the analog component. For example if `peak = 300` and `analogRead() = 301`, you are going to ignore that even though it is really close. I would try using a range like `int value = analogRead(A0); if (value >= peak-10 && value <= peak+10){....`

Comment: Shouldn't it return    0 for     i if     peak and     analogRead are never equal? Nevertheless, I'll try out your suggestion and see what it does. Also, how do you make certain portions of your text grey? I keep trying to do that but I can't.

Comment: I'm saying there might be a bit of randomness in the reading. Sometimes you get a lot of matches, but in those cases where you only get a few, you might really be getting a lot of close matches that you are ignoring.

Comment: For the code formatting, put the code in backticks. For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: I'm trying to detect the peaks for a 1 Hz signal for 3 seconds, and so I expect at most 3 peaks. The issue is I get too many matches.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't getting that from the question. You are reading the sensor many, many times per second so you could be reading the same value over and over. Maybe add a `delay()` in the loop. Have you looked at the waveform of the signal? You can use [SerialPlotter](https://learn.adafruit.com/experimenters-guide-for-metro/circ08-using%20the%20arduino%20serial%20plotter) to get a visual of what the signal looks like. PS, I'm not an electrical engineer. Maybe the guys at [arduino.se] will be more helpful.